# why failed to call android_view_Surface_getSurface on android 7

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am using android_view_Surface_getSurface call to get native surface from the java surface object in my JNI code of android 7 app, but if failed when I run the app on an android 7 device;
the error msg:
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: fid == null
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to GetObjectField

I think it means the gSurfaceClassInfo.mLock is invalid, but I don't know how to resolve, any suggestion? or other reson?

part of the native code:

```
static jint testSetDisplay (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject jsurface){
    sp<IGraphicBufferProducer> bufferProducer;
    if(jsurface != NULL){
        sp<Surface> surface(android_view_Surface_getSurface(env, jsurface));
        if (surface != NULL){
            bufferProducer = surface->getIGraphicBufferProducer();
            ALOGD("set display for pvr\n");
            return test_setDisplay(bufferProducer);
        }else{
            ALOGE("get surface failed!\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    ALOGE("invalid surface param!\n");

    return 0;
}

static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
    {"setDisplay", "(Landroid/view/Surface;)I", (void *)testSetDisplay}
};

static int register_test_disp(JNIEnv *env){
    return AndroidRuntime::registerNativeMethods(env, "com.test.jnimethods.nativeMethods", gMethods, NELEM(gMethods));
}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved){
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint ret = -1;

    if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK){
        ALOGE("ERROR:  get env failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = register_test_disp(env);
    if (ret < 0){
        ALOGE("ERROR: regist pvr disp failed\n");
        return -1;
    }else{
        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I don't know how to format code in commet, so I updated it in my question